# Closed beta testing to production

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed one app and added as closed beta testing using email address. It works fine so now I want move it to production, then what steps are needed, I am not able to see promote to production button on developer UI.

Comment: Do you have enough privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application in "apps/publish" go to "Manage Releases" in that "Manage beta" you will have option for "Promote to production" from there you can promote your app to production